# Generating RPM file for a react project

Tags: node.js, reactjs, node-modules, rpm, rpmbuild

I would like to generate/create an RPM file for my React Project. Basically the output of `react-scripts build` would create a `build folder` that contains all my assets that can be directly deployed into the web server.
  I would like to bundle the whole build folder into an RPM file. The intention is to give rpm instead of handover build folder directly for my application deployment.

Comment: Quick google search found https://www.npmjs.com/package/rpm-builder . However I am wondering why RPM specifically? Zip is much more widespread

Answer (score -1):

If the solution mentioned by apokryfos doesn't work you can check this out.
Although you can eject and then make it work but here's another solution without the need to eject, by just creating a webpack.config.js file at the root of project with:

```
const path = require("path")
const UglifyJsPlugin = require("uglifyjs-webpack-plugin")
const glob = require("glob")

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    "bundle.js": glob.sync("build/static/?(js|css)/main.*.?(js|css)").map(f => path.resolve(__dirname, f)),
  },
  output: {
    filename: "build/static/js/bundle.min.js",
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: ["style-loader", "css-loader"],
      },
    ],
  },
  plugins: [new UglifyJsPlugin()],
}
```

Change the package.json to this:

```
...
    "build": "npm run build:react && npm run build:bundle", 
    "build:react": "react-scripts build", 
    "build:bundle": "webpack --config webpack.config.js", 
...
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but this doesn't suites to my requirement.